# LiveObjects receive only 'Activity logs' instead of 'Uplinks/Downlinks' messages from device

Tags: lorawan, orange-api

I'm setting up some sensors on my Orange LiveObjects LoRa with a routing to my server, but I'm having trouble:

- My sensor is well provided on LoRa LiveObjects and it status is `activated` (On liveObjects and on the management app).
- I'm using the generic profile `Generic_classA_RX2SF12`
- It send some uplinks/downlinks messages.
- The uplinks/downlinks messages are interpreted as `Activity Logs` instead of `Messages`
- The logs can't be used with my routing rule.

I'm using ACS-Switch Ineo sense sensor.

I've tried to:

- Delete and add again the sensor
- Add the sensor using liveObjects interface
- Add the sensor using liveObjects API
- Set the sensor on another account of LiveObject and it works well (I received some uplinks/downlinks messages)
- Set the streamId with `!uplink`
- Use a FIFO
- Deactivate and reactivate the sensor on LiveObjects
- Reset the sensor connection so it send again `join request` that was `success` again

It seems to be a LiveObjects bug with my account since it works fine on another.

Does anyone already had the same bug ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by "The uplinks/downlinks messages are interpreted as Activity Logs instead of Messages"

What kind of routing do you use and do you route on the same manner on your two Live Objects acccounts ?

regards

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, 

In LiveObjects interface: 
In "Activity Logs" tab, there are the "join requests"/"success", but there are uplinks and downlinks messages too.
Those messages aren't in the "Uplink"/"Downlink" tabs of the concerned device.
The problem is that those payloads must be in the "Messages" instead of "Activity Logs" tab to be routed following my rule.

Before routing the messages I'd like LiveObejcts to display them in the right place.
I set an HTTP push on both accounts with the same route !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there may be something wrong with you account (for example created with a wrong offer). You should contact your support so that they could inspect your account configuration.

Regards